# JPA LazyInitializationException?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, lazy-initialization

I am using jquery for UI , Struts2 as Action , JPA for Data Access Layer. The issue I am facing is that I am getting LazyInitializationException when I am trying to retrieve values from the database . I am getting the below stacktrace :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.singpost.ctf.core.persistence.CtfTxn.ctfTxnAttribs, no session or session was closed
```

By default the `Fetch="LAZY"` , the code is working fine when I changed the Fetch type to `EAGER`, I don't know what I have to do further. I am stuck in the middle .

Comment: there are around dozens of questions about this exception on stackoverflow, and more on other websites. Did you check any of them?

Comment: @Bozho , since i didnt get the solution what i want , so only i recreated the topic . its not that i didnt refer any other resource and posted here and I can see a lot of links in the right side of the screen refering LazyInitializationException , but none helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to access a lazy fetched attribute from an entity JPA tries to access the database again to fetch the data. your problem is that at this time you're outside of the transaction. there are many ways to extend your transaction, e.g. using openSessionInViewFilter

( [Hibernate/Spring: failed to lazily initialize - no session or session was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041259/hibernate-spring-failed-to-lazily-initialize-no-session-or-session-was-closed) )

what i personally prefer is to create transfer objects, one for every page you want to show, only including necessary data. you only need to map your entities into those transfer objects, e.g. using the dozer mapper, which is really powerful and convenient.
that way it's much easier to manage transactions, and secondly you don't use database entities in your frontend, because you frontend doesn't need to know anything about your persistence layer.