# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session exception while trying to add collection

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am developing a website using spring/hibernate. I have a domain class 'Answer' as below,

### Answer.java

```
@Entity
public class Answer {
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name="Answer_comment",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ANSWER_ID"),
           inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COMMENT_ID"))
    private Collection<Comment> comment;

   -------------------------------------
   -------------------------------------
}
```

So I have One To Many relation among Answer and Comment entities.

To test this I am using below code,

```
Answer commentAnswer = answerService.getAnswer(1001);

   Comment comment2 = new Comment();
   comment2.setId(1004);
   comment2.setBody("I cannot agree with your answer..because ...");
   comment2.setUser(userService.getUser("ss"));
   //commentService.create(comment2);

   Comment comment3 = new Comment();
   comment3.setId(1005);
   comment3.setBody(" Yes I agree with your answer...sorry for my previous comment");
   comment3.setUser(userService.getUser("ss"));
   //commentService.create(comment3);

   ArrayList<Comment> commentList = new ArrayList<Comment>();
   commentList.add(comment2);
   commentList.add(comment3);

   commentAnswer.setComment(commentList);

   answerService.editAnswer(commentAnswer);
```

I am getting an existing Answer - 1001. And trying to add 2 comments newly created to that answer's comment collection. And saving that answer object.

When I run this I am receiving the below error,

```
 org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy 
 - no Session at the line -- commentAnswer.setComment(commentList);
```

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: There is a pretty good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041259/hibernate-spring-failed-to-lazily-initialize-no-session-or-session-was-closed

Comment: @chrislovecnm - Thanks for the link .. gained some knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Well .. I got this working. I am using HibernateTemplate.load method for loading the Answer entity. Now I changed it to HibernateTemplate.get method for loading the Answer entity. It is working now.